# First Tab Open on page Load

Tags: jquery, accordion

I just set up a new accordion on my page called "Accordion A" - http://dadu.be/accordion-a-1.1/documentation/documentation.html#integration

You can view this here for the product description:
http://first-base.businesscatalyst.com/basic-tees/booker-shirt

I am having trouble getting the first tab to automatically be opened on load, can anyone help?

Comment: Is this - http://dadu.be/accordion-a-1.1/documentation/documentation.html#integration - the link taht is meat to have your accordion, because there doesn't seem to be an accordion being created, or any script to create it?

Comment: Post your script so I can try to add something, I think a function that on load runs a .animate addClass .expanded may fire it.

Comment: I just tested it with adding .expanded aria-expanded="true" and .content style="height: 100%" did it. But I need your script

Answer (score 0):

well, have you tried this? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/
read please :D bye and good luck

or you can trigger the click on page load, so it simulates a click and opens the acordion, bye.again